# Angular Error: Cannot find control with path 'instructions -> 1 ->action'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to build a form. This form has the below structure. My users need to be able to create any amount of entries for the instruction fields.

```
...
  this.buttonForm = this.fb.group({
    instructions: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
            action: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
            data: this.fb.group({
                message: this.fb.control(""),
                mediaName: this.fb.control(""),
                mediaType: this.fb.control(""),
                commandName: this.fb.control(""),
                commandTrigger: this.fb.control("")
            })
        })
    ]),
    name: this.fb.control("", Validators.required),
    dimensions: this.fb.group({
        width: this.fb.control(5, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]),
        height: this.fb.control(5, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]),
        positionX: this.fb.control(5, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]),
        positionY: this.fb.control(5, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)])
    })
});

}

...

get instructionAray() {
    return this.buttonForm.get("instructions") as FormArray;
}

public addInstruction() {
    this.instructionAray.push(this.fb.control(""));
}
```

Below is the HTML for the component (excluding the non array items).

```
<ng-container formArrayName="instructions">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let instruction of instructionAray.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                <div class="flex flex-col gap-4 border border-solid border-red-300 p-2">
                    <select #action  formControlName="action" class="formBackground"
                        (change)="resetInstruction(i, $event.target)">
                        <option value="Command">Command</option>
                        <option value="Media">Media</option>
                        <option value="Message">Message</option>
                    </select>
                    <div *ngIf="action.value == 'Message'" >
                        <div class="flex flex-row gap-x-2" formGroupName="data">
                            <p>Message:</p>
                            <input type="text" formControlName="message" class="formBackground ml-2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="action.value == 'Media'" formGroupName="data">
                        <div class="flex flex-row gap-x-2">
                            <p>Media:</p>
                            <input type="text" formControlName="mediaName" class="formBackground ml-2">

                        </div>
                        <div class="flex flex-row gap-x-2 mt-2">
                            <p>Type:</p>
                            <select formControlName="mediaType" class="formBackground ml-2">
                                <option value="soundEffect">Sound Effect</option>
                                <option value="imageGif">Image / GIF / Static</option>
                                <option value="video">Video</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="action.value == 'Command'" formGroupName='data'>
                        <div class="flex flex-row mt-2 gap-x-2">
                            <p>Name:</p>
                            <input type="text" formControlName="commandName" class="formBackground ml-2">
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex flex-row mt-2 gap-x-2">
                            <p>Trigger:</p>
                            <select formControlName="commandTrigger" class="formBackground ml-2">
                                <option selected value="Manual">Manual (Default, only option)</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button (click)="delete(i)" class="bg-red-500 text-white rounded-xl self-center p-2">Delete Instruction</button>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>

        <button (click)="addInstruction()" class="bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-xl self-center p-2 mt-1">
            Add Instruction</button>
```

I'm running into a problem when I try to display the form array data. The first item in the array with the defualt properties displays fine. However, when I add another item to the form array it fails with the below error.

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'instructions -> 1 -> action'
    Angular 11
    ButtonFormComponent_ng_container_40_Template button-form.component.html:68
    Angular 26
    RxJS 6
    Angular 23
    ButtonFormComponent_Template button-form.component.html:108
    Angular 12
    BoardComponent_ng_template_3_Template board.component.html:43
    Angular 8
    openTemplateSheetMenu board.component.ts:52
    BoardComponent_div_2_Template__svg_svg_click_1_listener board.component.html:23
    Angular 24
    BoardComponent_div_2_Template board.component.html:23
    Angular 9
    BoardComponent_Template board.component.html:20
    Angular 2
core.mjs:6412:22
```

I've been stuck on this for a few days now with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating this error to plain English;

You are creating a `formArray` and you are supplying a default object `formGroup` to it `OnInit`. At this point of time you created a `formGroup` by default inside your formArray. So in your array you have an object at **index 0**.
Thus, when you press the `addInstruction()` you are pushing a new object to the array. Meaning an object at **index 1**. That's why the compiler complains about the absence of a control named `action` at **index 1** when you push the new object by pressing `addInstruction()`. In the supplied code above, the `addInstruction()` does not create a new object that includes the shape of the object you set by default at **index 0**. It only pushes an abstract `formControl` to the `formArray`.

So you need to refactor as follows:

1- Declare a property in your class of type `FormArray` named instructions

```
public instructions: FormArray
```

2- Rework the `addInstruction()`:

```
addInstruction() {
    this.instructions = this.buttonForm.get("instructions") as FormArray;
    this.instructions.push(this.createInstructions());
}
```

3- add a new method named `createInstructions()`

```
createInstructions(){
   return this.fb.group({
           action: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
            data: this.fb.group({
                message: this.fb.control(""),
                mediaName: this.fb.control(""),
                mediaType: this.fb.control(""),
                commandName: this.fb.control(""),
                commandTrigger: this.fb.control("")
            })
})}
```

4- Remove the `get instructionAray()`

It is not recommended to call methods that way in your template. For performance reasons use direct properties. Knowing that you have the `buttonForm` already in your `HTML` you can access your `formArray` in the `*ngFor` as follows:

```
this.buttonForm.get('instructions')['controls']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to push a **FormGroup** inside the FormArray instead of FormControl.

like this

```
public addInstruction() {
    this.instructionAray.push(
      this.fb.group({
        action: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
        data: this.fb.group({
          message: this.fb.control(''),
          mediaName: this.fb.control(''),
          mediaType: this.fb.control(''),
          commandName: this.fb.control(''),
          commandTrigger: this.fb.control(''),
        }),
      })
    );
  }
```

You should also use the entire html content inside a form tag with the formGroup. like this.

```
<form [formGroup]="buttonForm">
  ....
  ....
</form>
```